# Allow muliple values in Oracle for an SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, oracle, reporting-services, visual-studio-2008

I have a query that gets the numbers 1 to 10. This query is being used in an SSRS report to filter out a larger dataset.

I would like to know how we would get 'ALL' - there is a 'allow multiple values' option in the parameter properties option but i think this just concatenates the numbers together so would be (1,2,3, etc) and therefore I'm not sure Oracle can deal with this.

My query to get ContractTypes -1 to 10:

```
WITH ContractTypes (ContractType) AS (
                         SELECT -1 FROM dual
                         UNION ALL
                         SELECT ContractType+1 
                         FROM ContractType
                         WHERE ContractType< 10)
SELECT *
FROM ContractTypes
```

My query to get the contractTypes in another dataset. I'm not sure if this needs to be changed to maybe split the string to deal with multiple values. I am using -1 to deal with nulls.

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE contract_type NVL(CONTRACT_TYPE, -1) = :contract_type
```

I am using visual studio 2008 to build my report and pl/sql developer for my oracle code.

Thanks all for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with ALL when using integers, I usually use 0 for ALL to keep it simple.

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE (
    contract_type NVL(CONTRACT_TYPE, -1) = :contract_type
    OR :contract_type = 0
    )
```

If you don't want the NULLs, you need to change the OR to

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE (
    contract_type NVL(CONTRACT_TYPE, -1) = :contract_type
    OR (CONTRACT_TYPE IS NOT NULL AND :contract_type = 0)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Good idea with the 0 but my question was in regards to how to obtain all the records - i.e ignore the where clause - I thought we could add a -2 or something which we could use in the case for all. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This was my work around; create a second column which adds `NULL` and `ALL` to -1 and -2 respectively. Then we use the `DisplayFigure` column in SSRS for the filter.

```
    SELECT
           ContractType, 
           CASE WHEN  ContractType = -2 THEN 'All'
                WHEN ContractType = -1 THEN'Null'
                ELSE to_Char(ContractType)  
                END AS DisplayFigure
    FROM ContractTypes
```